# PostgreSQL loop through millions of records?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table 'location_signals' with about 250 million records with an index on the ID field. The table has ID, timestamp, Lat, and Lon (and a couple of other columns that aren't used).
Each ID could have thousands of Lat/Lon entries with different timestamps. I have a routine that is passed the ID, it fetches all records for that ID, and returns back a circle with the highest concentration of Lat/Lon.

The above had worked very well when we had ten thousand records, but when we imported more data, it is not able to process this anymore. The logic is as follows:

- Select unique IDs using "select ID from location_signals group by ID" (limiting to 1500 only), one issue here is that data timestamp is not in ideal format, so this is being done:

  ```
     SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') AS ts, * 
      FROM  location_signals 
      WHERE (
      extract(hour from TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI')) > '18' 
      OR  extract(hour from TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI')) < '06'  
      )
      AND \"DID\" = '$did'

      LIMIT 1500
  ```
- Pass IDs to routine

I believe the issue is because looping over millions and of that timestamp matter, or maybe something else. Any input would be highly appreciated.
Maybe doing things in batches also? If so, how?

Comment: And what is the data type for this `timestamp` column ? (a bad name for a column, BTW)

Comment: Limiting without ordering makes little sense.

Answer (score 5):

You should really fix your `timestamp` column to be a real timestamp.  Storing date/time value as strings is a really bad idea.  Naming the columns as if they were stored as the proper datatype -- well, in my mind that borders on malpractice.

Because you want to search on a time range, you can create an index on an expression:

```
create index idx_location_signals_id_time on location_signals(did, to_timestamp(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI')::time));
```

Then you can expression your `where` logic as:

```
where did = ? and
      (to_timestamp(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI')::time >= '19:00:00'::time or
       to_timestamp(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI')::time < '06:00:00'::time
      )
```

This should use the index for the full expression.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i think that would play a very big role in optimizing...i'm getting syntax error for the "::time" part (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"), should it be timestamptz ?

Comment: @roynaufal . . . No, the parentheses just didn't balance.